# Get same Azure Function Queue Trigger code to target 2 different queues based on app settings

Tags: msbuild, azure-functions, queuetrigger

I have an azure function that I'd like to have target 2 different queues.
I don't really want to have 2 separate repositories to manage and to try to keep them identical.  For testing my functions, I've been using precompiler statements and thought I might be able to simply expand that like this:

```
public static class ProdIndividualParse
{
#if DEBUG
    [FunctionName("TESTIndividualParse")]
    [Timeout("60:00:00")]
    public async static Task Run([QueueTrigger("parse-to-cosmos", Connection = "QueueAddress")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)

#elif RELEASE
     [FunctionName("PRODIndividualParse")]
    [Timeout("10:00:00")]
    public async static Task Run([QueueTrigger("prod-cosmos-parse", Connection = "QueueAddress")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)

#elif DEV
     [FunctionName("DEVIndividualParse")]
    [Timeout("10:00:00")]
    public async static Task Run([QueueTrigger("dev-cosmos-parse", Connection = "QueueAddress")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)

#endif
```

(no idea how to format this properly with the '#' signs)

I have tried adding a key-value pair to the settings of the dev environment:
CONFIGURATION DEV to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queue name can be taken from Application Setting. Add a setting called e.g. `myqueuename` and then define your function as

```
[FunctionName("IndividualParse")]
[Timeout("10:00:00")]
public async static Task Run([QueueTrigger("%myqueuename%", Connection = "QueueAddress")] 
    string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
```

Obviously, you can set different values for Dev vs Test Vs Prod environments, as long as they are in separate Function Apps or slots.